# Java - ArrayList Output

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, split

I created an arraylist in Java called **rows**. Now I have a text file which contains information regarding a program (for example: DRAMA-Film A-2.5hours-hi) which is put into a string called **strLine**. **strLine** is then split and put into the arraylist **rows**.

Can anyone tell me why nothing is being output with the **system.out.println** statement?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class Processing
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
  try{

  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");

  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine = null;

  List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {


        String[] row = strLine.split("-");
        rows.add(row);

  }
  System.out.println(rows.toString());

  in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean that _nothing_ is being printed?

Comment: Have you debugged it? is it reaching the syso statement? Have you test if you access the file correctly?

Comment: @Ted Hopp Netbeans gives me no output, despite telling me build successful

Comment: Sorry I missed something: `[[Ljava.lang.String;@1b0bf9a, [Ljava.lang.String;@f32dde]`

Comment: There must be at least something printed. What is printed?

Comment: So, you don't have any problem. You should close the question.

Comment: Are you asking why it is not printing anything? because it does print something ([[Ljava.lang.String;@5472fe25])
if you mean why it doesn't print what you want it's because you have printed the ArrayList object not it's contents. use a for to iterate through the contents.

    for(String[] strings : rows)
     for(String string : strings)
      System.out.println(string);

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why are you creating so many streams? why just:

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just print an array, you need to print the parts of it.

```
for (String[] row : rows)
{
  for (String part : row)
    System.out.print(part + " ");
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is printing out the default representation of an array list. The symbols you are seeing output are the String array references that you are storing in this list. If you want more detailed output then you will need to code for it.

```
for(final String[] row: rows) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row);
}
```

As an example.

Comment: All I want is to split the text in the text file and put them into an array which is then put into the arraylist. I did not understand what you actually mean, but aren't strings put as strings into an array? I mean, why did they change ?

Comment: You've accomplished your stated goals. The symbols you are seeing printed out e.g. `[Ljava.lang.String;@1b0bf9a` are ***array*** references. The same arrays you are storing into your `ArrayList`. If you want to see the element in each individual array then you need to use code like I've shown in my answer.

Comment: I still get the same output :/

Comment: @Brian All objects have a toString() method, but it is not magic: some objects don't have a toString() method which provides a string representation of their content in the way you would want to see it. `rows` is a List<String[]>, and there it doesn't have a toString() method which prints it the way you want (how would it know how you want to separate the String arrays and the String array elements? Commas? Separate lines?). That's why you have to provide your own implementation such as in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The default `toString()` method generates an internal string that represents the unique object. If you want to print a formatted string of the array contents, you can do this:

```
for (String[] row : rows) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Comment: I still get the same output :/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print out an array of String and are expecting it to look like a string.

```
  System.out.println(rows.toString());
```

When you call that, by default it prints out every element in the list, but each element, as you've programmed it is an instance of String[], not String. You need to go a step deeper, inception style to get the results you expect.

Try adding a method like so:

```
    public static void print(List<String[]> list) {

     for(String[] arr : list) {
         StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
         for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             buff.append(arr[i]);
         }
         System.out.println(buff.toString());
     } 
 }
```

and then call `print(rows);`

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayList` implementation of `toString()` prints the list using the `toString()` implementation of its elements.  Array objects' implementation of `toString()` doesn't print the array contents; instead, you need to use `Arrays.toString()`.  So you can either iterate over the list and print each array separately (see Ted Hopp's and Perception's answers), or if you really want to print it all in one go you can implement your own print method, something like this:

```
<T> String collectionOfArrsToString(Collection<T[]> collection) {
    // Adapted from AbstractCollection.toString() implementation
    Iterator<T[]> i = collection.iterator();
    if (!i.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        T[] tArr = i.next();
        sb.append(Arrays.toString(tArr));
        if (!i.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```